# Matlab: How to run code using multi threading/parallel computing?

Tags: multithreading, matlab

I have Matlab code that simulates something called the 2-D Lid Driven Cavity Flow. In this code I have the following structure:

```
for i = 1:timeStep
  %Lets call this Part 1
  for a1 = 1:N 
    for b1 = 1:N
    %calculates things
    end
  end
  %Lets call this Part 2
  for a2 = 1:N 
    for b2 = 1:N
    %calculates things
    end
  end
  %Lets call this Part 3
  for a3 = 1:N 
    for b3 = 1:N
    %calculates things
    end
  end 
end
```

Since Part 1, Part 2, and Part 3 are independent pf each other I would like to compute them in parallel, or multi thread them, every time there is a timeStep (every iteration of primary for loop). Is there any way I can achieve this? 
Thanks!

I include my code to to reference:

```
Nx = 50;
Ny = 50;
numTimesteps = 10000;
reynoldsNum = 1000;
dt = 0.0025;
numIter = 100000;
Beta = 1.5;
maxErr = 0.001;
ds = 1/(Nx + 1);
x1 = 0:ds:1;
x2 = 0:ds:1;
time = 0;
boundarySpeed = 1;

PHI = zeros(Nx+2, Ny+2);
OMEGA = zeros(Nx+2, Ny+2);
U = zeros(Nx+2, Ny+2);
V = zeros(Nx+2, Ny+2);
x2d = zeros(Nx+2, Ny+2);
y2d = zeros(Nx+2, Ny+2);
PRESSURE = zeros(Nx+2, Ny+2);
B = zeros(Nx+2, Ny+2);
pressureOLD = zeros(Nx+2, Ny+2);
W = zeros(Nx+2, Ny+2);

for i = 1:Nx+2
    for j = 1:Ny+2
        x2d(i,j) = x1(i);
        y2d(i,j) = x2(j);
    end
end

for timeStep = 1:numTimesteps   

    if(mod(timeStep,10000) == 0)
        disp(timeStep);
    end

    OLDPHI = PHI;
    OLDOMEGA = OMEGA;
    OLDPRESSURE = PRESSURE;

    parfor parJob = 1:4 

        switch parJob
%{
----------------------------------
   STREAM FUNCTION CALCULATION
----------------------------------
%}
        case 1
        for iter = 1:numIter
            ERRMATRIX = OLDPHI;
            for i = 2:Nx+1
                for j = 2:Ny+1
                    PHI(i,j) = (1/4) * Beta * (OLDPHI(i+1,j) + OLDPHI(i-1,j) + OLDPHI(i,j+1) + OLDPHI(i,j-1) + ...
                               ds * ds * OLDOMEGA(i,j)) + (1 - Beta) * OLDPHI(i,j);
                end
            end
            Err = 0;
            for i = 1:Nx+2
                for j = 1:Ny+2
                    Err = Err + abs(ERRMATRIX(i,j) - PHI(i,j));
                end
            end
            if (Err <= maxErr)
                break;  
            end
            OLDPHI = PHI;   
        end
%{
----------------------------------
BOUNDARY CONDITIONS FOR VORTICITY
----------------------------------
%}
        case 2
        for i = 2:Nx+1
            for j = 2:Ny+1
                OMEGA(i,1) = -2 * OLDPHI(i,2) / (ds * ds); % bottom wall
                OMEGA(i,Ny+2) = -2 * OLDPHI(i,Ny+1) / (ds * ds) - 2 * boundarySpeed / ds; % top wall
                OMEGA(1,j) = -2 * OLDPHI(2,j) / (ds * ds); % right wall
                OMEGA(Nx+2,j) = -2 * OLDPHI(Nx+1,j) / (ds * ds); % left wall
            end
        end 
%{
----------------------------------
     VORTICITY CALCULATIONS
----------------------------------  
%}  
        for i = 2:Nx+1
            for j = 2:Ny+1
                W(i,j) = -(1 / 4) * ((OLDPHI(i,j+1) - OLDPHI(i,j-1)) * (OLDOMEGA(i+1,j) - OLDOMEGA(i-1,j)) ...
                         - (OLDPHI(i+1,j) - OLDPHI(i-1,j)) * (OLDOMEGA(i,j+1) - OLDOMEGA(i,j-1))) / (ds * ds) ...
                         +(1 / reynoldsNum) * (OLDOMEGA(i+1,j) + OLDOMEGA(i-1,j) + OLDOMEGA(i,j+1) + ...
                         OLDOMEGA(i,j-1) - 4 * OLDOMEGA(i,j)) / (ds * ds);

            end
        end

        OMEGA(2:Nx+1,2:Ny+1) = OLDOMEGA(2:Nx+1,2:Ny+1) + dt * W(2:Nx+1,2:Ny+1);

        time = time + dt;

        for i = 1:Nx
            for j = 1:Ny
                x2d(i,j) = x1(i);
                y2d(i,j) = x2(j);
            end
        end

%{
----------------------------------
      U AND V CALCULATIONS
----------------------------------
%}
        case 3
        for i = 2:Nx+1
            for j = 2:Ny+1
                U(i,j) = (OLDPHI(i,j+1) - OLDPHI(i,j)) / (2 * ds);
                V(i,j) = -(OLDPHI(i+1,j) - OLDPHI(i,j)) / (2 * ds);
                U(:,Ny+2) = 1;  
                V(Nx+2,:) = 0.0;
            end
        end
%{
----------------------------------
      PRESSURE CALCULATIONS
----------------------------------
%}
        otherwise
        for i = 2:Nx+1
            for j = 2:Ny+1
                PRESSURE(i,j) = (1/4) * (pressureOLD(i+1,j) + pressureOLD(i-1,j) + pressureOLD(i,j+1) ...
                                + pressureOLD(i,j-1)) - (1/2) * (((((OLDPHI(i-1,j) - 2 * OLDPHI(i,j) + ...
                                OLDPHI(i+1,j)) / (ds^2)) * ((OLDPHI(i,j-1) - 2 * OLDPHI(i,j) + OLDPHI(i,j+1)) / (ds^2))) ...
                                - (OLDPHI(i+1,j+1) - OLDPHI(i+1,j-1) - OLDPHI(i-1,j+1) + OLDPHI(i-1,j-1)) / (4 * (ds^2))) * ds^2);
            end
            pressureOLD = PRESSURE;
        end
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parfor to run jobs in parallel.

```
result = cell(3, 1);
parfor k = 1:3
    result{k} = ['result-' num2str(k)]; 
    switch k
      case 1
          disp('do part one')

      case 2
          disp('do part two')

      otherwise
          disp('do part three')
    end
end
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, but end up  with errors such as "The variable PHI in a parfor cannot be evaluated" or "The variable OMEGA in a parfor cannot be evaluated". Any hints as to why that is happening?

Comment: you cannot share variables between threads, but you can either use cell array, or use three diferent variables (one per part) to save result of your computation and __after__ parfor union them.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the cell arrays? I am not sure what you are trying to get across.

Comment: @David, I edited the code to show how one can accumulate results from parallel computations using cell array. I also tested now, it also works with matrix, but i remember that this trick worked only with cell array. May be it depends on matlab's version? I've tested on 2015b now.